# Spooky Java Reflection Bug

Tags: java, excel, reflection

So, here is the problem. I'm attempting to use reflection in Java to define a type of 'view' for output to an excel sheet through ordered method declarations. (ordered numerically)

and in theory, this should work just fine, and it does to a point.

The issue is that the reflective method seemingly randomly decides to work sometimes, and not the others. It's not throwing an exception, it's finding the method names without any trouble, but as soon as it hits the boolean check for whether or not the method starts with the appropriate tag, it will sometimes stop at j = 5. Here's the code of the method to clarify:

```
public boolean objectWriter(List<Object> input, String sheetName, int startingRow, String tag){
    ArrayList<Object> myList = new ArrayList<>();
    jxl.write.Number number;
    Label label;

    //This is just an internal counter since we're using a for-each loop. 
    int j;
    try{
        for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++){
            j = 0;
            //we want to iterate over all of the available methods in the given class with reflection
            for (Method m: input.get(i).getClass().getMethods()){
                //Check to see if the method name has our requested tag, plus the appropriate counter
                //tacked on, and ZERO parameters, in our case.
                myLog.debug("this is our boolean check: " + m.getName().startsWith((tag + j)));
                if (m.getName().startsWith((tag + j))){
                    myLog.debug("m.getname inside: " + m.getName());
                    //Invoke the method, give it's return value to r (return)
                    final Object r = m.invoke(input.get(i));
                    //Since we defined in the requirements of this class that it must be a string
                    //those types of methods returned, this works just fine, just case it to
                    //String (Since String extends object) and call it a day. 
                    if (isNumeric((String)r)){
                        //if it's a number, make a number object out of it. 
                        number = new jxl.write.Number(j, startingRow + i
                        , Double.parseDouble((String)r)
                        , buildNumberFormat((String)r));

                        myList.add(number);
                    }else{
                        label = new Label(j,startingRow + i,(String)r);
                        myList.add(label);
                    }
                    j++;
                }
            }
        }
    }catch(IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException ex){
        myLog.error("There was an error working through the point class with reflection.", ex);
        return false;
    }
    boolean successfulWrite = myExcelWriter.writeInformation(myList, sheetName);
    myExcelWriter.resizeColumns(18, sheetName);
    return successfulWrite;

}
```

So, as you can see above, it reflectively looks for a caller-defined 'tag' in the method names, plus a number. so if i had a method with something like:

```
public String get0(){}
public String get1(){}
public String get2(){}
```

etc. etc. and I gave this method the tag 'get' it would pull out all three of those methods in the specified order. Also, it's defined in the requirements of using this particular method for the return values to all be Strings, so that isn't the issue I'm pretty sure. 
the strange part is I can't see why the boolean check on the line `if (m.getName().startsWith((tag + j)))` would start failing at j=5 ***SOMETIMES***

Anyway, if anyone has any idea, I'd really appreciate it. I'm pretty stuck here.

It's also worth noting, that j=5 is going to be the 'else' clause every time for the data set I gave it. Which stands out to me as more than a coincidence, but I can't see anything wrong with it.

**EDIT**

It's also worth nothing that the probability of it working exactly as expected (pulling out all of the properly enumerated methods, etc) increases SIGNIFICANTLY (close to 99% working) if I run an operation on 'm' before the boolean check. Such as how I print out that boolean statement right before the actual statement? that made it work almost every single time. But that certainly can't be a solution.

**EDIT #2**
As requested, I went ahead and moved the println to a debug log, this is a truncated version, but it essentially repeats the pattern inside 29 times, also interesting, it seems that if I send the output to my logger and not to the console, that aforementioned probability of success goes back down to what it is without it... strange...

```
09:02:45,881 DEBUG [root] this is our boolean check: false
09:02:45,881 DEBUG [root] this is our boolean check: false
09:02:45,881 DEBUG [root] this is our boolean check: false
09:02:45,881 DEBUG [root] this is our boolean check: false
09:02:45,881 DEBUG [root] this is our boolean check: false
09:02:45,881 DEBUG [root] this is our boolean check: false
09:02:45,881 DEBUG [root] this is our boolean check: false
09:02:45,881 DEBUG [root] this is our boolean check: false
09:02:45,881 DEBUG [root] this is our boolean check: false
09:02:45,881 DEBUG [root] this is our boolean check: false
09:02:45,881 DEBUG [root] this is our boolean check: false
09:02:45,881 DEBUG [root] this is our boolean check: false
09:02:45,881 DEBUG [root] this is our boolean check: false
09:02:45,881 DEBUG [root] this is our boolean check: false
09:02:45,881 DEBUG [root] this is our boolean check: false
09:02:45,881 DEBUG [root] this is our boolean check: false
09:02:45,881 DEBUG [root] this is our boolean check: false
09:02:45,881 DEBUG [root] this is our boolean check: false
09:02:45,882 DEBUG [root] this is our boolean check: false
09:02:45,882 DEBUG [root] this is our boolean check: false
09:02:45,882 DEBUG [root] this is our boolean check: false
09:02:45,882 DEBUG [root] this is our boolean check: false
09:02:45,882 DEBUG [root] this is our boolean check: true
09:02:45,882 DEBUG [root] m.getname inside: xGet0Label
09:02:45,882 DEBUG [root] this is our boolean check: true
09:02:45,882 DEBUG [root] m.getname inside: xGet1MD
09:02:45,882 DEBUG [root] this is our boolean check: true
09:02:45,882 DEBUG [root] m.getname inside: xGet2Easting
09:02:45,882 DEBUG [root] this is our boolean check: true
09:02:45,882 DEBUG [root] m.getname inside: xGet3Northing
09:02:45,882 DEBUG [root] this is our boolean check: true
09:02:45,882 DEBUG [root] m.getname inside: xGet4TVD
09:02:45,882 DEBUG [root] this is our boolean check: true
09:02:45,882 DEBUG [root] m.getname inside: xGet5Date
09:02:45,882 DEBUG [root] this is our boolean check: false
09:02:45,882 DEBUG [root] this is our boolean check: false
09:02:45,882 DEBUG [root] this is our boolean check: false
09:02:45,882 DEBUG [root] this is our boolean check: false
09:02:45,882 DEBUG [root] this is our boolean check: false
09:02:45,883 DEBUG [root] this is our boolean check: false
09:02:45,883 DEBUG [root] this is our boolean check: false
09:02:45,883 DEBUG [root] this is our boolean check: false
09:02:45,883 DEBUG [root] this is our boolean check: false
09:02:45,883 DEBUG [root] this is our boolean check: false
09:02:45,883 DEBUG [root] this is our boolean check: false
09:02:45,883 DEBUG [root] this is our boolean check: false
09:02:45,883 DEBUG [root] this is our boolean check: false
09:02:45,883 DEBUG [root] this is our boolean check: false
09:02:45,883 DEBUG [root] this is our boolean check: false
09:02:45,883 DEBUG [root] this is our boolean check: false
09:02:45,883 DEBUG [root] this is our boolean check: false
09:02:45,883 DEBUG [root] this is our boolean check: false
09:02:45,883 DEBUG [root] this is our boolean check: false
09:02:45,883 DEBUG [root] this is our boolean check: false
09:02:45,883 DEBUG [root] this is our boolean check: false
09:02:45,883 DEBUG [root] this is our boolean check: false
09:02:45,883 DEBUG [root] this is our boolean check: false
09:02:45,883 DEBUG [root] this is our boolean check: false
09:02:45,883 DEBUG [root] this is our boolean check: false
09:02:45,883 DEBUG [root] this is our boolean check: false
09:02:45,883 DEBUG [root] this is our boolean check: false
09:02:45,883 DEBUG [root] this is our boolean check: false
09:02:45,883 DEBUG [root] this is our boolean check: false
09:02:45,884 DEBUG [root] this is our boolean check: false
09:02:45,884 DEBUG [root] this is our boolean check: false
09:02:45,884 DEBUG [root] this is our boolean check: false
09:02:45,884 DEBUG [root] this is our boolean check: false
09:02:45,884 DEBUG [root] this is our boolean check: true
09:02:45,884 DEBUG [root] m.getname inside: xGet0Label
09:02:45,884 DEBUG [root] this is our boolean check: true
09:02:45,884 DEBUG [root] m.getname inside: xGet1MD
09:02:45,884 DEBUG [root] this is our boolean check: true
09:02:45,884 DEBUG [root] m.getname inside: xGet2Easting
09:02:45,884 DEBUG [root] this is our boolean check: true
09:02:45,884 DEBUG [root] m.getname inside: xGet3Northing
09:02:45,884 DEBUG [root] this is our boolean check: true
09:02:45,884 DEBUG [root] m.getname inside: xGet4TVD
09:02:45,884 DEBUG [root] this is our boolean check: true
09:02:45,884 DEBUG [root] m.getname inside: xGet5Date
```

Comment: It's going to be hard for us to help you with only part of the code, but that part of the code containing things we really don't need. It would be *much* easier to help you if you could provide a short but complete program demonstrating the problem. Also, given that you've got logging, it would help if you'd show the logs...

Comment: Working sporadically would make me suspect threading issues.  You have no synchronization on this method.  myExcelWriter looks like a shared, mutable data member.  If yes, see if that's the root cause.

Comment: @duffymo I agree, it feels like a threading problem, but this is all running off of the main (javafx application) thread. Unless java sparks off a new thread for a reflective call that I wasn't aware of, I can't see that being the problem. 
Jon skeet - unfortunately it's a relatively non-trivial task to come up with a supporting example that has the same characteristics. This method probably has about 2000 lines of supporting code. I might have some time later to try and hack something together to reproduce this behaviour on a small scale though.

Comment: also, @jon skeet my logs aren't throwing any output at all, so, 0 errors, 0 warns from any type of exception throughout the program linked to this problem

Comment: If none of your logging is having any effect, that would suggest you've found no methods... or that your logging isn't working. If you don't *at least* see "this is our boolean check" then that's the first thing you should look at.

Comment: Oh, that. I had that going to the console for a quick check before I put this up, really it wasn't meant to make it on here. I don't have my log4j scraping the output yet, I could send it to my debug log, but it's easier just to go ahead and see it print out for me. That line you referenced prints out successfully every time, it just starts returning false a bunch at 5, but very rarely, since as mentioned in my edit, as soon as I observe the value of m through an action on it (.getName() for example) it increases the chance of success significantly.

Comment: Also, sorry if that came off as argumentative, just thought dumping into the comment logs, it was a good suggestion :) I moved the println to the debug log and added some of the output in the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out! so there was an inherent bug with the way I was approaching the 'ordering' of the methods that were being checked. Although I anticipated the 'getMethods()' to return the methods of a class in no particular order, if one of the methods came to me in the wrong order, **It never got re-checked!** It was simply by happenstance that sometimes the numerically ordered first methods would come before the later ones, leading to the correct behaviour. most often, it just so happened that the numbered methods 0-5 would come AFTER 6-14 (that was the range in this data set).

So, my solution, was to create a 'pool' of rejected method names, and then every time the check failed, iterate through the pool of rejects, and make sure one of them didn't fit the bill either. If it was none of those, it wasn't a method we cared about.

This slows things down a touch, but it's in the range of milliseconds.

solution code:

```
public boolean objectWriter(List<Object> input, String sheetName, int startingRow, String tag){
    ArrayList<Object> myList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Method> methodList = new ArrayList<>();
    jxl.write.Number number;
    Label label;

    //This is just an internal counter since we're using a for-each loop. 
    int j;
    try{
        for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++){
            j = 0;
            //we want to iterate over all of the available methods in the given class with reflection
            for (Method m: input.get(i).getClass().getDeclaredMethods()){
                //Check to see if the method name has our requested tag, plus the appropriate counter
                //tacked on, and ZERO parameters, in our case.
                if (m.getName().startsWith((tag + j))){
                    //Invoke the method, give it's return value to r (return)
                    final Object r = m.invoke(input.get(i));
                    //Since we defined in the requirements of this class that it must be a string
                    //those types of methods returned, this works just fine, just case it to
                    //String (Since String extends object) and call it a day. 
                    if (isNumeric((String)r)){
                        //if it's a number, make a number object out of it. 
                        number = new jxl.write.Number(j, startingRow + i
                        , Double.parseDouble((String)r)
                        , buildNumberFormat((String)r));

                        myList.add(number);
                    }else{
                        label = new Label(j,startingRow + i,(String)r);
                        myList.add(label);
                    }
                    j++;
                }else{
                    methodList.add(m);
                    for (int x = 0; x < methodList.size(); x++){
                        if (methodList.get(x).getName().startsWith((tag + j))){
                            //Invoke the method, give it's return value to r (return)
                            final Object r = methodList.get(x).invoke(input.get(i));
                            //Since we defined in the requirements of this class that it must be a string
                            //those types of methods returned, this works just fine, just case it to
                            //String (Since String extends object) and call it a day. 
                            if (isNumeric((String)r)){
                                //if it's a number, make a number object out of it. 
                                number = new jxl.write.Number(j, startingRow + i
                                , Double.parseDouble((String)r)
                                , buildNumberFormat((String)r));

                                myList.add(number);
                            }else{
                                label = new Label(j,startingRow + i,(String)r);
                                myList.add(label);
                            }
                            j++;
                            //methodList.remove(x);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }catch(IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException ex){
        myLog.error("There was an error working through the point class with reflection.", ex);
        return false;
    }
    boolean successfulWrite = myExcelWriter.writeInformation(myList, sheetName);
    myExcelWriter.resizeColumns(18, sheetName);
    return successfulWrite;

}
```

This is a good lesson that when you try to impose an order on an inherently un-ordered list, make sure you're careful, because if you mess it up (like me!) it'll feel like VERY undefined behaviour.